# Select Banco Oracle - Constraint

Tags: oracle

Bom dia pessoal, se alguém puder me ajudar, preciso de uma consulta que me retorne as constraints de uma tabela e seus tipos de dados. Estou tentando montar um gerador de procedure para facilitar, demora muito para ficar criando procedures. Neste select não me traz o tipo de dados.

```html
SELECT DISTINCT SYS.USER_CONS_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS NATURAL JOIN SYS.USER_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PRODSERV';
```

Comment: Algo do tipo? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference

Comment: Me parece que nenhuma delas me trouxe ou que eu preciso, por exemplo eu preciso do campo tipo COD_UNID e o seu tipo de dado por exemplo NUMBER, para que eu possa criar os parâmetros da procedure. create or replace procedure sp(SP_CODI_UNID number).....

Comment: o type da coluna se tem em USER_TAB_COLUMNS  SELECT USER_CONS_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME , USER_TAB_COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE 
FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS, USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE USER_CONS_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  USER_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
AND USER_CONS_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME =  USER_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME

Comment: Pessoal utilizei da forma que eu tinha imaginado mesmo, que e a mesma ideia do Reginaldo Rigo, utilizei duas consultas e um for duplo, criando uma nova lista apenas com as constraints...

Comment: Ulisses, o site funciona diferente de um fórum, o nosso "resolvido" é quando você marca uma resposta como aceita, como você já fez, isso já marca a pergunta como "resolvida" :)

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numa consulta unica não é possível, mas em duas ou mais seria assim:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from 
all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABELA' 

SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type  
from user_constraints where table_name = 'TABELA'


SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type, column_name
from user_constraints natural join user_cons_columns
where table_name = 'TABELA'
```